# camel-sql consumer DB connection issue

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am using Apache Camel with Spring boot. I am using my spring boot app as jar without any server.

In app I am having a Camel-SQL consumer route with delay of 1000. This consumer then further calls other route which use splitter and parallel processing.

Through Jprofiler I have observed that my DB connection are not getting closed which are opened through consumer.

I also have dbcp2 settings in application.properties and using Oracle DB. I am observing this connection issue for the first time. Did anyone also faced the same issue at anytime? Or do I need to add any other configuration.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my Oracle configurations:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="server.placeholder" persistent-id="name.of.company.datasource">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="db.host" value="host"/>
        <cm:property name="db.port" value="1521"/>
        <cm:property name="db.instance" value="dbname"/>
        <cm:property name="db.user" value="user"/>
        <cm:property name="db.password" value="password"/>
        <cm:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
        <cm:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <cm:property name="defaultReadOnly" value="false" />
        <cm:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
        <cm:property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <cm:property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="2" />
        <cm:property name="maxWait" value="-1" />
        <cm:property name="maxIdle" value="8" />
        <cm:property name="minIdle" value="1" />
        <cm:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <cm:property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <cm:property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="-1" />
        <cm:property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <cm:property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <cm:property name="testWhileIdle" value="false" />
        <cm:property name="softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="-1" />
        <cm:property name="lifo" value="true" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value= "${driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.instance}" />
  <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
  <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
  <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
  <argument ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool" >
  <argument><null/></argument>
  <argument value="${maxActive}" />
  <argument value="${whenExhaustedAction}" />
  <argument value="${maxWait}" />
  <argument value="${maxIdle}" />
  <argument value="${minIdle}" />
  <argument value="${testOnBorrow}" />
  <argument value="${testOnReturn}" />
  <argument value="${timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
  <argument value="${numTestsPerEvictionRun}" />
  <argument value="${minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />
  <argument value="${testWhileIdle}" />
  <argument value="${softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />
  <argument value="${lifo}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory" >
  <argument ref="connectionFactory" />
  <argument ref="connectionPool" />
  <argument><null/></argument>
  <argument value="${validationQuery}" />
  <argument value="${defaultReadOnly}" />
  <argument value="${defaultAutoCommit}" />
</bean>

<bean id="poolingDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="pooledConnectionFactory">
  <argument ref="connectionPool" />
</bean>

<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="poolingDataSource"> 
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oracle/db"/>
        <entry key="datasource.name" value="jdbc/oracle/db" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

Maybe it will help you.
I think DB connection just doesn't have time to go back to the pool between queries.
You need to configure the connection timeout and similar parameters (idle params, *minEvictableIdleTimeMillis*, *timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis*, *numTestsPerEvictionRun*).

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for the reply. I have properties related to dbcp2 already in place. Problem is connection are not getting closed due to which new connection cannot be created.

Comment: @gomzee, IMHO, the maxActive value was exceeded during the operation of the routes.
This is because the connections do not have time to return to the pool.

Comment: Alexey, DB config is:
<blink>
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=30
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=40
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.dbcp2.min-dle=2
</blink>
And my maxMessagesPerPoll=10. So for processing 396 records my program stops at 380 records always, after processing 380 records it cannot get DB connection.

And through JProfiler I can see all active connections as memory leaks.